# Link separator CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, separator

It's easy for who know

In this code:

```
$maximo = 12;
    $inicio = (!$this->uri->segment(3)) ? 0 : $this->uri->segment(3);
    $config['base_url'] = 'clientes/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->clientes_items_m->count_all();
    $config['per_page'] = $maximo;
    $config['next_link'] = '>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '<';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li><a><b>';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b></a></li>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $pagination = $this->pagination->create_links();

    //Busca no banco as noticias
    $items = $this->clientes_items_m->limit($maximo,$inicio)->get_all();
```

i want put separator like this( `<span id="divider">/</span>` ) between link of page but i don't know how to do that.
anybody help me??

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li><a><b>';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b></a></li><span id="divider">/</span>';
```

Comment: i try to that but the divider appear after the last page when i put it at ['cur_tag_close'] and when i am on the first page if i put it at ['cur_tag_open'] appear before the first page

Answer (score 0):

See if this works...

In your pagination code:

```
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<span class="divider">';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '/</span>';
```

Or you could leave the forward slash out of that code, and use CSS:

```
span.divider::after {
  content: "/";
}
```

By the way, and a bit off topic, but you're going to have multiple of these divider slashes, so instead of giving them an id, you should use a class (`.divider`).

Comment: when i on the first page the divider appear like that "1 2/ >"

Comment: you have to add in the code of raheel shan above, with the `cur_tag_open` and `cur_tag_close`, so it works on the "current" link as well.

Comment: But current can be the last number of the page soo that <code><span id="divider">/</span></code> put the divider after the last number like this <code> < 1 / 2 / </code> and i want just between the numbers.

Comment: Perhaps strip off the last slash with CSS: `span.divider:last-child::after{ content:""; }` (untested)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Generic Pagination Class](http://www.grargs.com/paginate.zip). I dont know if CI pagination class supports seperating the links? I found out about his class [here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/152169/).

Here is an example how to use from the link above:

```
// Load the library
$this->load->library('paginate');

// Setup config array
$config = array(
        'total_items' => 100,
        'items_per_page' => 20,
        'current_page' => 1,
        'page_link_separator' => '&bull;'
    );

// Pass in config array to library
$this->paginate->configure($config);

// Get the pagination array
$this->data['pages'] = $this->paginate->get();
```

You should be able to easily replace `&bull` with any separator you like.

Hope this helps.